# Why webdriverio can't find element?

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

```
await this.browser.url(url);
await this.browser.pause(5000);
const link = await $('a');
```

It opens the URL but after a pause I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDevTools' of undefined
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to use $ as browser object funtion

```
const link = await this.browser.$('a');
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else seeing this issue, I later realized I was importing the $ command from the package, which was not correct. It was added without my knowledge – I think VS Code auto-imported while writing more tests.

```
import $ from 'webdriverio/build/commands/browser/$'; <<-- Removed this and it worked fine.

describe('Connect Apps / Manage Apps', async () => {
  before(async () => {
  const elem = await $('.results');
  await elem.waitForDisplayed(5000, true);
});
```